# AWS SDK javascript in node js returns access denied

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, access-denied

Guys when I tries to list all my buckets, it works as expected. So then I can make sure my setup is correct.
The problem is when I try to list the content of a bucket:

I have a route `/:bucket` in node js

```
app.get('/:bucket', function (req, res) {
    var bucket = req.params.bucket;
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var params = {
        Bucket: 'bucket'
    };
    s3.listObjects(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else
            console.log(data);           // successful response
    });
});
```

This doesn't work and it return acces denied.

Here is the bucket policy:

```
{
  "Id": "Policy...............",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt..........",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

and this is the error I get:

```
{ [AccessDenied: Access Denied]
  message: 'Access Denied',
  code: 'AccessDenied',
  region: 'us-east-1',
  time: Thu Aug 04 2016 13:14:56 GMT+0100 (CET),
  requestId: '.............',
  extendedRequestId: '.............................................',
  cfId: undefined,
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: ........... } 'AccessDenied: Access Denied\n    at Request.extractError (/home/azouz/PFE/Docker/PBD/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:524:35)\n    at Request.callListeners (/home/azouz/PFE/Docker/PBD/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)\n    at Request.emit (/home/azouz/PFE/Docker/PBD/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)\n    at Request.emit (/home/azouz/PFE/Docker/PBD/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:661:14)\n    at Request.transition (/home/azouz/PFE/Docker/PBD/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)\n    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/home/azouz/PFE/Docker/PBD/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)\n    at /home/azouz/PFE/Docker/PBD/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10\n    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/azouz/PFE/Docker/PBD/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)\n    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/azouz/PFE/Docker/PBD/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:663:12)\n    at Request.callListeners (/home/azouz/PFE/Docker/PBD/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)\n    at Request.emit (/home/azouz/PFE/Docker/PBD/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)\n    at Request.emit (/home/azouz/PFE/Docker/PBD/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:661:14)\n    at Request.transition (/home/azouz/PFE/Docker/PBD/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)\n    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/home/azouz/PFE/Docker/PBD/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)\n    at /home/azouz/PFE/Docker/PBD/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10\n    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/azouz/PFE/Docker/PBD/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)'
```

Comment: Did you supply the right creds?

Comment: Yes in .aws/config . When trying to list All the buckets associated with my account it returns them.

Comment: Are you sure you'r requesting bucket the right way. You have a string `'bucket'` instead of variable `bucket` here: `Bucket: 'bucket'`

Comment: Another thing that might be, do you want to show the buckets under `my_bucket`?

Comment: Oh m'y bad. You are right. I will try this out when I go back yo work and I will let you Know if it worked.